# How to make aggregate boundaries become strongly consistent instead of eventually consistent?

Tags: domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts

I have an aggregate root, **Agent**, in one bounded context that is devoid of authentication concerns:

## Bounded context A:

```js
interface Agent {
  id: AgentId,
  firstName: FirstName,
  lastName: LastName,
  email: Email
}
```

Agents are also responsible for registering new agents. That is, an **Agent** is also a factory for other agents.

Whenever a new Agent is registered, an event `AgentRegistered` is published.

## Bounded context B:

Every agent needs an **Account** to log-in.

This bounded context B subscribes to `AgentRegistered` events; whenever an agent is registered, it creates an account for it (passwords are generated).

```js
interface Account {
  agentId: AgentId,
  email: Email,
  password: String
}
```

## The "issue"

It is a business requirement that emails should be unique. That is:

- An **Agent** should not be able to register new agents that have an used e-mail.

- An **Account** should not be created if the e-mail is already being used.

It is also a business requirement that *every* agent should have an account.

In bounded context A, I can simply check if there are agents with the same e-mail by querying in their repository. If not, `AgentRegistered` event is published.

But, what happens if, somehow, there is an Account with the same e-mail? The whole process (registering the Agent and creating its account) should be invalidated.

## Possible solutions?

1. Make the process of registering an agent and then creating an account a saga/long-running process.

A process manager would tell the `Agent` aggregate to register an `Agent`. If successful, it will tell the `Account` bounded context to create an account. If unsuccessful, it will rollback by telling the `Agent` aggregate to unregister the agent. This is ridiculously complex for something so simple.

2. Make **Account** an Entity of **Agent**, instead of a separate Aggregate Root.

**Agent**'s interface would then look something like:

```js
interface Agent {
  id: AgentId,
  firstName: FirstName,
  lastName: LastName,
  email: Email,
  account: {
    // wait, no need to put email here
    password: String
  }
}
```

It also makes the aforementioned business requirement that *every* agent must have an account more explicit.

However, it mixes concerns; **Agent** should not care about authentication concerns.

Is there a better solution, or am I just overcomplicating things?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming there could be other personas (apart from Agents) who might be creating accounts, because of which you might end up in a situation where an email address might be present in the Accounts BC but not in Agents BC.

You can do this to check for an email address across *both* contexts:

[image: Interactions between Bounded Contexts]

You publish an `AccountCreated` event from Accounts BC and consume it in the Agents BC to maintain a read-only Accounts model. This model can have bare-minimum data; just the email address will suffice for this requirement. The model is read-only, so you can always wipe the data and repopulate it whenever necessary.

Now you can validate for used email addresses in both the Agents repository and the Accounts Readonly model.

Note that there will be a slight lag between account creation and populating the read-only model. So you can potentially have conflicts if two different contexts add the same email address in the same instant. But if this is a rare occurrence and you can survive the occasional blip, this is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I do think , however, that the bounded context A should not know anything about Accounts, much less expect a response from bounded context B. Don't you think that's a lot of coupling? Thanks

Comment: Account domain is not sending a response back to Agent here; it is publishing an event for the rest of the world. So there is no coupling at all. Domain Events are preferred for inter-aggregate and inter-bounded-context communication for eventual consistency. Also, it is realistic (and pretty standard) that bounded contexts depend on each other; Context Maps describe their relationships and contact points.